# How to Process a CSV File from Power Apps/Automate into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv, azure-sql-database, power-automate

So as an overview of what I am trying to do

1. User Uploads a csv file to Power Apps
2. The Power App sends that file to a Power Automate Flow
3. The Flow take the file contents and sends it to a SQL Stored Procedure as a NVARCHAR(MAX) param
4. ???

[Power Automate Flow Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84mup.png)

So I have all that working, and the contents of the CSV come in fine as a complete text string parameter in the SQL stored procedure, that has the proper new line formatting and everything from the file.

Awkwardly MS SQL has the Bulk Insert tool that if I had the file saved somewhere would work great, but doesn't to my knowledge have a way to process it if it's just a string. I have seen answers where people setup like 5 different sql functions and then run a proc that uses them to parse the string, and I'd really prefer to utilize a more official/built-in method to do so if possible.

I was thinking maybe take the string, and then in the stored procedure save that to temporary csv or something, then I could use bulk import from that? My concern is I want it to be versatile enough that regardless if this is a local SQL server or an Azure SQL server it'll work, so I'm not sure if you can save a file locally on Azure SQL? Also in terms of saving it somewhere beforehand like to sharepoint/blob storage as I'm not sure if the bulk insert would have a way to properly authenticate since I don't want the files to be just publicly accessible?

Alternatively I'm fine with processing the file in either the Power App or Power Automate Flow stages, I'm just not sure that I can. Flows have some csv actions but they're all third party and seem to require subscriptions and whatnot.

Maybe I could make an Azure function to do it? I'd like to have as few moving pieces as possible (and fewer things to configure) but if that'd be a more reliable way to read the file and I'd need blob storage otherwise then maybe it should be an option.

Another idea I had that I have no idea if it's realistic would be maybe I could save that file/file-contents to an environment variable in Power Platform that I could then use with a PowerQuery action or something?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why use Power Automate for something that can already be done infinitely better with BULK INSERT, the `bcp` command line tool or SSIS? Why use a stored procedure at all? If you want a GUI-based tool, that's Azure DataFactory, not Power Automate. Power Automate is the completely wrong tool for the job

Comment: Because it is an import that triggered from a power app and needs to be run dynamically from there as part of an end user functionality, by all means if there is a good way to do it directly from power apps I'm all for that